# Can I use external markup with knockout JS 2's default template system?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

atm I have something like this:

```
$('#fish').append("<div data-bind='foreach: rows'>" +
  "<div ..." +
  "<p>...</p>"..);
```

and I don't want nasty inline templates, so I put the template into a `<script id='fishtemplate' type='text/html'></script>`

I want to `append(fishtemplate)`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'fishtemplate', foreach: row }"></div>
```

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html (section **Note 2: Using the “foreach” option with a named template**)